# My internet is driving me nuts

Tags: networking, internet, download, internet-connection

My internet is slowly driving me nuts. I have a max download speed of 14 mbits and a upload of 2,4 mbits. Ive never had issues with the upload speed itself but m download speed, I am well aware that the promised 14 mbits are never gonna get achieved and i dont have a problem with that but i feel like Im getting ripped off. When I run a speedtest on my pc wich is connected to the router over LAN it tells me I have a current download of about 11 mbits which would be fine if that was to be true but its not. If I download lets say a game via Steam (or anything else really) The max download seems to be cut at 1,8 mbits which is insultingly low, I dont have a download speed cap in any form, whether on Steam or windows or whatever.
I dont know what to do, maybe change contracts/company?

Comment: Contact the support of your provider.  And be sure that it is not the server that is slow.  ;-)

Comment: Are you certain the steam speed is in Mbit/s? 1.8MByte/s ≈ 14 Mbit/s.

Comment: What internet access technology do you use? (Speeds seem to be consistent with that ADSL2 AnnexM might reach.) Also, which equipment exaclty is there (router model, network card)?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to login to your cable modem and look at the signal levels, which will be displayed as dBmv, and the signal to noise ratio (SNR), which will be in dB. Your cable modem documentation will tell you what ideal signal levels are, and desired SNR. In general, you want SNR > 23.5 dB, and ideally, SNR > 30 dB.

You can get greater signal level by having fewer splits in your cable line. Trying to minimize the number of splits that go to TVs, for example.

You can also install a bidirectional amplifier at the point the cable enters your home. Something like the [ARRIS BDA-42-1-AR-R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0792PTCFP). Or call your provider and have them fix it.

Comment: What made you think it was a docsis connection? These poopy speeds made me think poor quality DSL.

Comment: Given an unspecific question, you have to make as some assumptions.